# Zend form field name as array

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

```
public function init()
{
    $txt = $this->createElement('text', '0')
            ->setBelongsTo('txt');
    $this->addElement($txt);

    $fields = $this->createElement('text', '0')
            ->setBelongsTo('fields');
    $this->addElement($fields);
}
```

But in this case one of fields is not displayed. How to make both field's arrays start from 0.
I could leave txt[] and fields[] but when I do `this->populate($_POST);` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in general. The second parameter you pass to the element has to be its name, which has to be unique (form field name). The `setBelongsTo` calls will not work because your elements do not have the respective names. What you are doing is to create an element with the name `0` and then overwrite it with another element, which is the one displayed. You will see this, if you look at your source code in the browser. If you're using `setIsArray` then you should make both elements belong to the same array.

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve but it should look more like this:

```
public function init() 
{
    $txt = $this->createElement('text', 'mytext')
                ->setBelongsTo('myarray');

    $this->addElement($txt);

    $fields = $this->createElement('text', 'myothertext')
                   ->setBelongsTo('myarray');

    $this->addElement($fields); 
}
```

Comment: Output of Your code will be `<input type="text" name="mytxet[mytext]" id="txt-txt" value="">`and I want `<input type="text" name="txt[0]" id="txt-0" value="">`

Comment: use `createElement('text', '0')`, `createElement('text', '1')`